# What is the right way to instantiate a controller in ASP.NET Core without using a DI container?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

In `Startup.ConfigureServices`, I have this piece of code:

```
services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(new LicenseKeyControllerActivator(keyService));
```

LicenseKeyControllerActivator looks like this:

```
public class LicenseKeyControllerActivator
    : IControllerActivator
{
    private readonly ILicenseKeyService _keyService;

    public LicenseKeyControllerActivator(ILicenseKeyService licenseKeyService)
    {
        _keyService = licenseKeyService;
    }

    public object Create(ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new LicenseController(_keyService);
    }

    public void Release(ControllerContext context, object controller)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

During the request-response lifecycle, the activator creates the controller, the `DataAnnotations`-based validations work, the filters filter, but no controller method is ever called. In fact, after the `set` is called on the DTO, `Release` is called immediately.

I'm not sure if this is [a routing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461959/attribute-routing-to-controller-action-isnt-working-in-asp-net-core), or a controller activator issue.

Comment: I am not sure what you try to accomplish. By default Controllers are **NOT RESOLVED** by the ASP.NET Core DI (see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-core/1949/dependency-injection/23212/resolve-controllers-viewcomponents-and-taghelpers-via-dependency-injection#t=201704181554355419976) but by the default implementation of the controller activator. If people want Controllers to be resolved by DI they need to explicitly opt-in for it

Comment: This absolutely seems a routing problem, because overriding the `IControllerActivator` _is_ the way to practice **Pure DI* in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Yes, it is. Routing is broken due to a bad ActionFilter. Sorry, I would delete or close my own question, because the question contains the answer.